# Edit custom column component while adding new row of Material Table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

With the React Material Table library, is it possible to render a custom component while adding a new row? I'm [using a custom component](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/custom-column-rendering) (a Material UI select box, actually), for the Expected Result column. When I add a new row, I only see a field for the Requirement column, not the Expected Result column. Is it possible to add an input for the Expected Result column of the new row as well?

[image: Material Table screenshot]

Another option is to not use custom components at all and instead use something like the Cell Editable Example of https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable. However, I'm not a fan of the extra clicks that it takes to edit the Expected Result, compared to directly using a Select field.

```js
import MaterialTable from 'material-table'
import { MenuItem, Select } from '@material-ui/core'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import update from 'immutability-helper'

type PassFailNA = 'Pass' | 'Fail' | 'N/A'

type RowData = {
    requirementId: number,
    requirementName: string,
    expectedResult: PassFailNA,
    expectedResultId?: number
}

export function ExpectedResultsTable(props: {
    scenarioId: number
}) {
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState<RowData[]>([{ requirementId: 1, requirementName: 'hello', expectedResult: 'Pass' }])
    const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar()

    const handleSelect = (id: number) => (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ name?: string; value: any }>) => {
        setTableData((tableData: RowData[]) => {
            const rowNum = tableData.findIndex(x => x.requirementId === id)
            return update<RowData[]>(tableData, {
                [rowNum]: { expectedResult: { $set: event.target.value } }
            })
        })
    }

    return (
        <MaterialTable<RowData>
            title=""
            columns={[
                {
                    title: 'Requirement',
                    field: 'requirementName'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Expected Result',
                    field: 'expectedResult',
                    render: (rowData) => (
                        <Select value={rowData.expectedResult} onChange={handleSelect(rowData.requirementId)}>
                            <MenuItem value="Pass">Pass</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="Fail">Fail</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="N/A">N/A</MenuItem>
                        </Select>
                    )
                }
            ]}
            data={tableData}
            editable={{
                onRowAdd: newRow =>
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            setTableData(tableData => update(tableData, { $push: [{ ...newRow, expectedResult: 'N/A'}] }))
                            resolve()
                        }, 1000)
                    })
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you are looking for, I think you should specify the `editComponent` property ( besides `render` ) when defining the column. That prop takes a function where you can define the component used during the edit or creation phase.

Here is an example I made with a boolean input:

```
  const tableColumns = [
    { title: "Client", field: "id" },
    { title: "Name", field: "name" },

    {
      title: "booleanValue",
      field: "booleanValue",
      editComponent: (props) => {
        console.log(props);
        return (
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={props.value}
            onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.checked)}
          />
        );
      },
      render: (rowdata) => (
        <input type="checkbox" checked={rowdata.booleanValue} />
      )
    }
  ];
```

Link to working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-checkbox-field-zlzzc). I hope that works for you!